# SetInterval is not working for async tasks in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, scheduled-tasks, setinterval

I am new to nodejs. I have implemented simple async task and it should run every 10 min. Here set Interval function should run every x minutes as given and value for the variable api key should be updated. I don't know what is missing in it.

Could anyone let me know where I am going wrong.

```
var  csgTokenFile= rfr('models/csg-token-gen');
var apiKey;

setInterval(function(req, res) {
    csgTokenFile.key(function(messages) {
          console.log("key: ",messages);
          apiKey = messages;
    })
}, 20000);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You didn't explain what's going wrong, also you are passing in `req, res` like it's a response to an HTTP request but those values will be undefined

Comment: No. Everything is fine.

Comment: First try lowering the timespan to 500 millisec something and then try it again and tell us what's happening.

Comment: The value to apiKey is not updating. @Dominic

Comment: The quoted code *will* call `csfTokenFile.key` every 20 seconds or so (very roughly), and assuming that calls its callback with a different `messages` value, that value *will* be saved in `apiKey`. So he problem isn't in the quoted code. I suggest using a debugger to watch what happens (`node-inspector`, for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code that when fixed can help you find the real problem - which is either in the `csgTokenFile.key()` function, its invocation or the expected behavior.

First of all, parameters in a function that is passed to `setInterval()` make no sense because it will be invoked with no arguments anyway. You're not using them here anyway but their presence is not a good sign because it seems that you may be confused about how it works.

Instead of this:

```
setInterval(function (req, res) {
    // ...
}, 20000);
```

use this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    // ...
}, 20000);
```

or this, because you're not using `this` anyway:

```
setInterval(() => {
    // ...
}, 20000);
```

Now, the interface and the implementation of the function `csgTokenFile.key()` remains a mystery (and this is the most important source of the problem here, as it's either the function that doesn't work properly or it's the other code that doesn't use that function properly  - it's impossible to tell without looking at the source code of `csgTokenFile.key()` - also the `rfr()` function is a mystery and may be relevant here) but it looks like it may be following the Node convention of error-first callbacks, in which case it will pass error as the first argument to the callback and the actual data as the second.

If the `csgTokenFile.key()` takes traditional Node-style callbacks then it should be used like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    csgTokenFile.key((error, messages) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log('Error:', error);
        }
        console.log("key: ", messages);
        apiKey = messages;
    })
}, 20000);
```

But as mentioned above it's impossible to tell from your question. It's just a hint.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting implementing style. Now, I am getting error as b25a312fd828a66bb00e82aba2546758ca929217f56be6303b5e24ee0d232434. This is similar to my result (output for messages). Are The order parameters correct?